# 18.04; login screens hangs after suspend or lock

Tags: 18.04, gnome

Ubuntu: 18.04.2, Gnome: 3.28.2

Behavior: workstation has been locked **or** suspended; wake workstation; enter the password; nothing happens, but the login screen continues to be displayed; this behavior is repeatable, frequent, but not always consistent (sometimes I am able to log in)

Ctrl + Alt + F1: takes me to a fresh login screen; enter the password; same behavior as above

Ctrl + Alt + F3: enter the password at the CLI; login successful

No hardware has changed and I am 99% sure none of the software either. I assume this is an issue with the Gnome shell, but I am not sure how to troubleshoot.

[hwinfo](http://www.filedropper.com/hwinfo)
[lspci](http://www.filedropper.com/lspci)

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Edit: 2019.05.04
This behavior came up after a few months of usage. Everything worked fine up until recently. My only option is to power down via CLI or Ctrl + Alt + F1.

Comment: I have been getting a similar issue as well, and reported it in Debbugs. Related issues are https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=250312, https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/-/issues/618, and https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=973831. I will edit this to reflect any progress.